# Регулярные выражение, замена текста

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, powershell

Пытаюсь разобраться с заменой текста.
Исходный текст:

```
12345
```

Необходимо оставить `135`.

Составил следующее условие:

```
(?<=1)\d(\d)\d(?=5)
```

Заменяю на `$1`, но в итоге получаю `15`

Почему не срабатывает замена на первую группу?

Comment: а как заменяете? язык указали бы и код привели бы, может вместо `$1` надо было `\1`? Ваша замена в php нормально работает

Comment: @BOPOH, c#, powershell 


        [regex]::replace("12345", "(?<=1)\d(\d)\d(?=5)", "$1")

Comment: Если исходить из имеющегося описания задачи, то проще всего сделать так [regex]::replace("12345", "[24]", "")

Comment: @playerone, проще тогда уже `str = "135"`, если серьезно, то ваш пример сработает не как надо на строке `2123454`, оставит только `135` (как и мой))), а надо чтобы осталось `21354`. Автор, с шарпом знаком плохо, поэтому надо подождать тех, кто знаком хорошо )

Comment: @BOPOH, а Вы понимаете как надо со строкой `abcde` или `54321` поступить? Я - нет.

Comment: @andy.37, судя по предложенной регулярке, в обоих случаях оставляем как есть

Comment: @BOPOH ну да, вы правы, я похоже не полностью уловил суть вопроса.

Comment: Ребята, Условие гораздо сложнее. Простоего уростил до 5 символов. Есть две опорные точки, в моем примере это 1 и 5. Идут они именно в такой последовательности. Внутри них много текста, в середине которого расположен необходимый. Нужно все выкинуть, оставив только необходимый текст, в моем случае, это цифра 3

Comment: @ИгорьИльяшенко я нашел в чем у вас проблема! Если в третьем параметре использовать одинарные кавычки, то результат получается правильный `[regex]::replace("12345", "(?<=1)\d(\d)\d(?=5)", '$1')` Объяснить причину не смогу, не разбираюсь в powershell. По понятным причинам в C# этой проблемы нет.

Comment: Кажется причина в том, что с двойными кавычками он интерпретирует `$1` как переменную. Ранее такой переменной ничего не было присвоено и следовательно она равна пустой строке. То есть, фактически, третьим параметром функции `replace` оказывается пустая строка. Вот и результат замены соответствующий. Если же использовать одинарные кавычки, то строка `'$1'` будет передана в функцию replace как есть. И дальше уже `replace` сам займется её интерпретацией.

Comment: О как все просто оказалось. Надо же было столько времени провозиться, а ошибка оказалась в штатных переменных powershell. 

Спасибо за помощь. Оформите как ответ, я закрою вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение проблемы - использовать в третьем параметре одинарные кавычки `'`.

`[regex]::replace("12345", "(?<=1)\d(\d)\d(?=5)", '$1')`

Причина в том, что с двойными кавычками PowerShell интерпретирует `$1` как переменную. Ранее такой переменной ничего не было присвоено, и следовательно она равна пустой строке. То есть, фактически, третьим параметром функции `replace` оказывается пустая строка. Вот и результат замены соответствующий. Если же использовать одинарные кавычки, то строка `'$1'` будет передана в функцию `replace` как есть. И дальше уже `replace` сам займется её интерпретацией.