# Замена текста при помощи регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, powershell

Продолжение темы:

[Регулярные выражение, замена текста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497300/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0/497383#497383)

Помогите модифицировать регулярное выражение: `(?<=1)\d(\d)\d(?=5)` таким образом, чтобы можно было получить несколько внутренних выражений.

Например исходный текст: 12345 преобразуется в 135 (как в прошлом примере). Однако, если необходимо выполнять замену для нескольких внутренних выражений: 12342642845, то совпадение не происходит (результатом должно быть 13685). Цифры 2 и 4 можно считать тоже опорными точками.

Можно ли как-то добиться универсальности выражения, чтобы срабатывало на любое количество? Можно конечно создать разные выражения для разных количеств вложенных элементов, но мне кажется это какой-то костыль.

Comment: Вы бы словами сформулировали точные правила как должна происходить вырезка. как бы сейчас выходит что достаточно просто выкинуть все 2 и 4. т.е. буквально глобальная замена `[24]` на ничего

Comment: Почти правильно уловили суть. Только не глобально выкинуть 2 и 4, а в рамках 1 и 5.

Comment: А у вас конструкции `\G` и `\K` работают ? Если так, то в глобальном режиме меняем `(1|(?!^)\G).*?\K[24](?=.*?5)` на ничего.

Comment: 1) вырезаем часть строки между 1 и 5 (`^[^1]*(1\d*5)[^5]*$`). 2) Из результата удаляем все 2 и 4 (`/[24]//`). А вообще, для того чтобы понять как должна работать регулярка одного примера обычно мало.

Comment: @andy.37, полагаю это нужно делать в 2 прохода?.. Надо бы делать за один запрос...

Comment: @Pincher1519 это, конечно, можно написать в одну строку, но вот насчет одного прохода, не знаю. Могу написать на перле/питоне, в С# мои познания -> 0, увы.

Comment: @Pincher1519 Вы мою регулярку не проверяли ? Во всем полностью PCRE совместимом она должна работать

Comment: @mike, это рекурсивный обход? Вроде сложность с ним на c#. Надо посмотреть на синтаксис для c#, попробую, спасибо.

Comment: @Pincher1519, на перле за 1 проход: `$source =~ s/^[^1]*|[24]|[^5]*$//g;`. Заменяем все, что не единица в начале, или все что не 5 в конце, или все (2 или 4) на ничто. Из `8881215345666` делает `11535`.

Comment: @Pincher1519 Нет, там не рекурсия. `\G` говорит после произошедшей замены одной цифры с этого места уже не пытаться заново искать 1, т.к. она осталась за пределами области видимости. А `\K` говорит что все выражение до нее надо считать не захватывающим, т.е. все что до нее работает как `(?<=)`, но при этом позволяет туда писать условия переменной длины вроде `.*`

Comment: @andy.37 Я так понял вопрос, что за пределами 1 и 5 ничего трогать не надо, только между ними

Comment: @Mike, а какая разница, что происходит за пределами крайних 1 и 5? Мы все равно выбрасываем эту часть)). Можно оставить копию исходной строки, если она нужна.

Comment: @andy.37 Изначальная регулярка, которая устраивала на более коротких строках ничего не делала, если в строке не находила 1... там же явное условие "только после 1"

Comment: Ну, получится пустая строка, если изначально не было 1 (или 5). Это же несложно проверить, и вывести исходную в этом случае.

Answer (score 1):

Пошел другим путем.

В итоге сделал два вызова разных регулярок. Первой убирал совпадения 42 внутри 15, а потом убирал 24 внутри 15. Жалко, что не получилось сделать в одно регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Всё от единицы до пятёрки не включая их, выкинув по цифре с каждого конца?

```
(?<=1)\d(\d*)\d(?=5)
```

А ещё можно заменять

```
(1)\d(\d*)\d(5)
```

на

```
\1\2\3
```

или (в других языках)

```
$1$2$3
```

Comment: Нет, задача несколько сложнее. 
Использовал цифры, чтобы проще описать регулярку. Можно попробовать со скобками:
[A]([B][C][D])[E]

Результатом должно получиться:
[A](BCD)[E]

Comment: @Pincher1519, непонятно.

Comment: В круглых скобках убиваем квадратные, вне круглых - не убиваем.

Comment: Кажется, для этого сгодится balancing group definition https://goo.gl/PUiBqi Там как раз в примерах скобки ловят (и вложенные). Я ещё с ним, правда, не разобрался, сложно показалось.